# What are the Pali or Sanskrit words for these things?

Tags: terminology

I think I know some of these, but the rest are a translation muddle. The west seems to **not** attempt to translate nirvana, sangha, dharma, mantra, mudra, buddha, bodhisattva (and probably a few more) and that for me is actually helpful. I expect that some of these correspond to multiple Pali/Sanskrit words.

**Enlightenment**. In English, it is an anachronistic reference to the European age of Enlightenment.

**Meditation**. This word predates the west's contact with Buddhism. I have no idea what non-Buddhist baggage it brings along.

**Loving-kindness**. This sounds like Christianity projected on Buddhism.

**Soul**. Seems like this is atman, but everyone seems determined to call it something like "self," which is for a man-in-the-street just a reflexive pronoun. (Does the self exist? Well, as much as any other pronoun, like "he" or "they")

**Reincarnation/rebirth**. Synonyms in man-in-the-street's English, but I've seen people argue passionately how Buddhism believes one but not the other, sort of like believing in leasing but not renting (which are synonyms).

**Repentance**. I know for sure this is a big deal in Chinese Buddhism.

**Pure/Purity**. Means scrubbed clean of earthly dirt. I know this is a metaphor, but somehow, after 2000 years it falls as flat as if I tried to use a computer metaphor to explain to a 500BC farmer how the brain and cellular DNA works.

**Heaven/Pure Land**.  Sukhāvatī comes to mind, but I'm not sure if this is a specific pure land, or the jargon for pure lands in general. Again, 'pure' makes it sound either homogenous or really well scrubbed, like a hospital. I'd rather just use whatever jargon word the originators used.

**Deity**. This in man-in-the-street English mean a god, or God, just like the one's the Christian's pray to. In Vajrayana, people seem to argue that yidams are something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Enlightenment - *bodhi* (awakening), *vimokṣa*, *vimukti* (liberation).
- Meditation -    *bhāvanā* (cultivation), *samādhi* (concentration), *śamatha* (calmness), *samāpatti*, *dhyāna*.
- Loving-kindness - *maitrī*.
- Soul - as permanent entity which doesn't exists is *ātman*. Soul as [*psyche*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soul) or mind is *citta*, *manas*, or as life force is *jīvita-indriya*.
- Reincarnation - is uncommon in Buddhist discourse.
- Rebirth - *pratisaṃdhi*. Where birth is *jāti* or *bhāva*.
- Pure - *śubha*.
- Heaven - *deva-loka*.
- Repentance - 懺 (ch'an) which is *kṣamā*.
- Pure land - *buddha-kṣetra*.
- Deity - *devatā*.

Comment: I think śubha means beautiful; suddha (śuddha in Skt) is pure.

Comment: @yuttadhammo 'Beautiful' is one of the [meanings](http://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/cgi-bin/tamil/recherche?dictionary=mwd&prst=exact&st=zubha), but also "*good (in moral sense) , righteous , virtuous , honest; pure (as an action)*".

Comment: Sure, but it's not the best literal translation for pure, that's all.

Comment: @yuttadhammo I thought MatthewMartin meant not just some abstract purity, but purity of action and personality, where *śubha* is good fit.

Comment: What is your source for thinking that?  It means literally 
"beautiful"; that it can be in some cases glossed as meaning "pure" doesn't make it a good fit. See http://sanskritdictionary.com/?q=%C5%9Bubha or http://dictionary.buddhistdoor.com/en/word/237402/subha or http://vedabase.net/s/subha - nowhere is it defined as "pure".

Comment: @yuttadhammo Because OP said '*clean of earthly dirt*', where 'earthly' I read as *mundane*, and not some physical dirt. *Śubha/subha* is definitely have connotations of [purity](http://www.palikanon.com/english/wtb/dic3_s.htm) and [cleanliness](http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.4:1:336.pali), and [goodness](http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.4:1:530.pali). Sobhana cittas and cetasikas are w/o defilements, i.e. *pure* in ethical sense.

Comment: the only reference to purity in your first link is parenthetical for subha-sa~n~naa; cleanliness in the PED is for the noun form, and it's not a literal translation; goodness is also not a literal translation. Sobhana cittas are so-called because it is beautiful to be without defilements; the word still doesn't mean "pure".

Comment: I even provided links to dictionaries where it says in plain text 'purity', 'cleanliness', and 'good'. (I have even more links.) And you say it still doesn't have such *meaning*. Just because you don't like something doesn't make it non-existent. "Noun form", "not a literal translation" - who cares? Word does **have** such *meaning* and *use* (in the context of actions), literal or not. If I'm correct that OP asked in the context of *ethics* then word is correct. Beauty in actions or personality **is** purity. It's not context of beautiful dance moves or material art form. It's ethics.

Comment: OP was asking for "the" word for it. subha isn't it. It just doesn't mean "pure", except in the same way as, say, anavajja (non-guilt) does - i.e. obliquely. The CEPD has eleven words for pure and none of them are subha. `"pure: (adj.) suddha; suci; nimmala; accha; pasanna; pūta; asaṅkiṇṇa; amissa; kevala; niddosa; anavajja."`

Comment: OP was asking how some Western ideas & words, which he thinks of, and which he tried to express sometimes metaphorically (note: not literally), is correspond to words in Buddhist discourse. Not just to accidental dictionary words, but to word & ideas of Buddhist discourse. Idea of ethical (persona & actions) purity (from defilements) **is** 'beauty'. Nowhere I said it's exhausting meaning for purity. I'm not against other translations. I just said that śubha *have* such reading in particular context. Several references I provided. If some dictionary not includes that, so what? Others do.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

There are many synonyms to the words given in the table. Only mentioning some of the popular words.

Comment: According to the discussion under this question: http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/3062/760 the translation of "enlightenment" should be bodhi, not nibbana.

Comment: The distinction made there is with regards to Magga & Phala nana.
More at: http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/mahasi/progress.html 

But the word 'enlightenment' is commonly used to refer to Nibbana.